# eslint - verify function object params

Tags: javascript, eslint, lint

background:

```
function myFunc({ param1 }) {
  ...
}
    
...
    
myFunc({ paramTypo1 })
```

Is there an eslint rule that detects such param typos inside function object params?

Comment: FWIW, this is something that TypeScript will help you with.

Comment: This sounds to me like you want to do type checking, which I would not expect to be performed by a linter. What about using TypeScript?

Comment: You are both right, but right now I have to use JS

Comment: Using JavaScript you might get something working by writing JSDoc for your function and using [eslint-plugin-jsdoc](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc). But for proper type checking, I highly recommend to use TypeScript. It's really easy to set up and integrate.